# My WordPress don't display the images that I've hardcoded

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm coding a site in WordPress and I'd like to have a bookmark star shown before a course name.

The thing is that the code works fine, I can see that it translates to the right place where the image is, but the image appears to not be found.

Is there any configuration I need to do to make this image to show or anything I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
$estrela = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/images/estrela.png';
$estrelaFavorito = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/images/estrela-favorito.png';

if ($isFavorito) {
    $img = $estrelaFavorito;
} else {
    $img = $estrela;
}

if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <div class="add-remove-bookmark" onclick="addToBookmark(<?php echo $user_id ?>, 'course', <?php echo $course_id ?>)" >
        <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="favoritos" width="20" height="20"/>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Results in:

```
<div class="add-remove-bookmark" onclick="addToBookmark(x, x, x)">
    <img src="/home/xxx/www/wp-content/themes/wplms_child/images/estrela-favorito.png" alt="favoritos" width="20" height="20">
</div>
```

---

Edit:

If I change to the code below, it works, but not really best practice:

```
$estrela = 'https://www.xxx.com.br/wp-content/themes/wplms_child/images/estrela.png';
$estrelaFavorito = 'https://www.xxx.com.br/wp-content/themes/wplms_child/images/estrela-favorito.png';
```

---

Solution:

I've replaced the variables `$estrela` and `$estrelaFavorito` for the code below and now it works!

```
$estrela = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/estrela.png';
$estrelaFavorito = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/estrela-favorito.png';
```

Comment: try to open your generated path in the browser to verify it

Comment: It redirects to another WordPress default page. I don't know how to change it.

Comment: `/home/xxx/www/wp-content/themes/wplms_child/images/estrela-favorito.png` redirects to another page?!

Comment: Yes, like a default page.

Comment: I've tried to change to the adress, please check where I edited the question, and it works...

Comment: you develop at a local machine? any `.htaccess` files? Or are there any redirections defined in the vHost / your Webserver?

Comment: i see...why not using relative paths?

Comment: Relative path you mean something like `../../images/estrela.png`?

Comment: yes, this is a relative path

Comment: Got it with another WordPress function, please check solution on my question, thanks for the help mate!

Comment: Ah, relative path didn't work either, I guess that is something of WorPress that don't let it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
//Returns an absolute server path
get_stylesheet_directory()
```

by

```
// return theme directory url 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri